# Pokemon game in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, performance, object-oriented, pokemon

I'm practicing my JavaScript skills by trying to create a Pokemon game. So far, I've made the dataset and the functions required to work the game. Can someone help me optimize the code and tell me why they made that change?

```
function pokemon(name, hp, critical_attack, lowest_attack, highest_attack) {
    this.name = name;
    this.hp = hp;
    this.critical_attack = critical_attack;
    this.lowest_attack = lowest_attack;
    this.highest_attack = highest_attack;   
}

var Charizard = new pokemon("Charizard", 90, 30, 1, 15);
var Blastoise = new pokemon("Blastoise", 95, 28, 1, 14);
var Venasaur = new pokemon("Venasaur", 100, 26, 1, 13);

var poke_choice = new Array ("Charizard", "Blastoise", "Venasaur")

function player(type, name, pokemon) {
    this.type = type;
    this.name = name;
    this.pokemon = pokemon;
}

var user = new player("User", "Arhum", "Charizard");
console.log(window[user.pokemon].hp)

for(i = 0; i<= 2; i++) {
  if (poke_choice[i] === user.pokemon) {
    poke_choice.splice(i,1);
  }
}  

var comp_choice = function() {
  return poke_choice[Math.round(Math.random())]
}

var comp = new player("Computer","Red", comp_choice());

var user_attack = function() {
  var uhigh = window[user.pokemon].highest_attack
  var ulow = window[user.pokemon].lowest_attack
  return Math.round(Math.random().toFixed(1)*uhigh)
}        

var comp_attack = function() {
  var chigh = window[comp.pokemon].highest_attack
  var clow = window[comp.pokemon].lowest_attack
  return Math.round(Math.random().toFixed(1)*chigh)
}     

console.log(window[comp.pokemon].name)
console.log(window[user.pokemon].name)
console.log(user_attack())
console.log(comp_attack())
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> ```
> function player(type, name, pokemon) {
>     this.type = type;
>     this.name = name;
>     this.pokemon = pokemon;
> }
>
> var user = new player("User", "Arhum", "Charizard");
> console.log(window[user.pokemon].hp)
> ```

There's some *really* strange and bad practices going on here, especially with the `pokemon` field. Here, you are relying on the fact that the string passed in will correspond with some variable on the global scope that is hopefully of the type `pokemon`.

That's not the right way to do things. Instead, `player` objects should be instantiated with the actual pokemon object itself:

```
var user = new player("User", "Arhum", Charizard);
```

Then, whenever you need to access information about the player's pokemon, rather than doing this:

```
window[user.pokemon]
```

You just do this:

```
user.pokemon
```

This is a lot safer, and follows practices much better.

---

> ```
> var user_attack = function() {
>   var uhigh = window[user.pokemon].highest_attack
>   var ulow = window[user.pokemon].lowest_attack
>   return Math.round(Math.random().toFixed(1)*uhigh)
> }        
>
> var comp_attack = function() {
>   var chigh = window[comp.pokemon].highest_attack
>   var clow = window[comp.pokemon].lowest_attack
>   return Math.round(Math.random().toFixed(1)*chigh)
> }
> ```

These two functions do exactly the same exact thing, except they are for two very specific instances of a class. This is also terrible practice, as nothing is flexible here and functions not only repeat themselves but rely on two very specific objects to be, again, in the global scope.

Instead, these two functions should become one instance method of the `player` class:

```
player.prototype.attack = function() {
  var uhigh = this.pokemon.highest_attack
  var ulow = this.pokemon.lowest_attack
  return Math.round(Math.random().toFixed(1)*uhigh)
}
```

Then, you should use this methods instead of those other two functions.

```
user.attack();
comp.attack();
```

*You may want to rename to `doAttack` as the wording can be confusing.*

---

> ```
> function player(type, name, pokemon) {
>     this.type = type;
>     this.name = name;
>     this.pokemon = pokemon;
> }
>
> var user = new player("User", "Arhum", "Charizard");
> ```

Are there any types other than "User" and "Computer"? If not, then you should turn this property into a boolean value something like this:

```
function player(isComputer, name, pokemon) {
    this.isComputer = isComputer;
    this.name = name;
    this.pokemon = pokemon;
}

var user = new player(false, "Arhum", "Charizard");
```

---

> ```
> var Charizard = new pokemon("Charizard", 90, 30, 1, 15);
> var Blastoise = new pokemon("Blastoise", 95, 28, 1, 14);
> var Venasaur = new pokemon("Venasaur", 100, 26, 1, 13);
>
> var poke_choice = new Array ("Charizard", "Blastoise", "Venasaur")
> ```

Now that we're done relying on these three pokemon variables to be in the global scope, we can clean up this part of the code, too.

We don't need to explicitly store the three pokemon variables anymore with their variable names; those can just go straight into the array. However, when we do that, we can no longer access the pokemon by name so it would be best to create a map/object for this situation:

```
var pokeChoice = {
    Charizard: new pokemon(...),
    Blastoise: new pokemon(...),
    ...
}
```

With this in place, this

> ```
> for(i = 0; i<= 2; i++) {
>   if (poke_choice[i] === user.pokemon) {
>     poke_choice.splice(i,1);
>   }
> }
> ```

can be simplified to:

```
if(pokeChoice.hasOwnProperty(user.pokemon.name)) {
    delete pokeChoice[user.pokemon.name];
}
```

---

Here is your full code now:

```
function pokemon(name, hp, critical_attack, lowest_attack, highest_attack) {
    this.name = name;
    this.hp = hp;
    this.critical_attack = critical_attack;
    this.lowest_attack = lowest_attack;
    this.highest_attack = highest_attack;   
}
var pokeChoice = {
    Charizard: new pokemon("Charizard", 90, 30, 1, 15),
    Blastoise: new pokemon("Blastoise", 95, 28, 1, 14),
    Venasaur: new pokemon("Venasaur", 100, 26, 1, 13)
};

function player(isComputer, name, pokemon) {
    this.isComputer = isComputer;
    this.name = name;
    this.pokemon = pokemon;
}
player.prototype.attack = function() {
    var uhigh = this.pokemon.highest_attack
    var ulow = this.pokemon.lowest_attack
    return Math.round(Math.random().toFixed(1)*uhigh)
}

var user = new player("User", "Arhum", pokeChoice.Charizard);
if(pokeChoice.hasOwnProperty(user.pokemon.name)) {
    delete pokeChoice[user.pokemon.name];
}

var comp_choice = function() {
    var pokeKeys = Object.keys(pokeChoice);
    var pokeAmt = pokeKeys.length;
    return pokeChoice[pokeKeys[Math.round(Math.random() * (pokeAmt-1))]]
}
var comp = new player("Computer","Red", comp_choice());    

console.log(user.attack())
console.log(comp.attack())
```

I made some other small changes here and there. If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

Also, the naming convection in JavaScript is:

- `PascalCase` for classes.
- `camelCase` for functions.

You are breaking these rules in some cases.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just got done with my exams and got to try this code out. Unfortunately, it's lost all its functionality. `comp_choice()` returns undefined which naturally gives an error when executing `comp.attack()`. Also, `if(pokeChoice.hasOwnProperty(user.pokemon.name)) { delete pokeChoice[user.pokemon.name]; }` doesn't work as the code treats the `user.pokemon` as a part of the `pokeChoice` array instead of the dictionary that it actually is. Please help, thanks!

Comment: @ArhumIshtiaq I think I fixed the first problem, but I'm confused by the second one; there is no pokeChoice array; there is only the dictionary/map/object.

Comment: @ArhumIshtiaq Bracket notation `foo[bar]` is used on objects, it's just that it's often used on arrays as `foo[0]` (as arrays are also objects).

Comment: But bracket notation is still not able to access `pokeChoice`. Is it possible for you to try and execute the code. I think you'll better understand if you see the errors that it's passing.

Comment: @ArhumIshtiaq it should be `user.pokemon` not `user.pokemon.name` I think.

Comment: @ArhumIshtiaq Fixed it finally; originally, the constructor for the player was only passing the pokemon name, and not the actual pokemon object.

Comment: @SirPython, do you have a suggested way that I can use to solve it as well?

Comment: @ArhumIshtiaq What do you mean? I've already updated my answer with the fixed code.

Comment: @SirPython My apologies, I didn't notice it on my phone, just saw it on the computer. Thank you!

Comment: I tried the code, it works but now pokeChoice has an undefined key as well, along with Charizard, Blastoise and Venasaur.

Comment: @ArhumIshtiaq Can you be more specific? The `delete` key basically makes a key undefined in an object. Perhaps I misunderstood the original intent of the snippet?

Comment: All it has to do is leave the `compChoice` with just two `pokeChoice` keys to choose from. Unfortunately if you run the program a couple of times, you'll observe that it may choose among the two remaining keys but at times also return an `undefined` value.

Comment: @ArhumIshtiaq Hmm... I'm having trouble reproducing that issue, and I've run it about 10 times now. Is there any other information you can provide?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41591/discussion-between-arhum-ishtiaq-and-sirpython).

Answer (score 7):

In addition to @SirPython's answer:

- Strict mode. Put `'use strict'` (or `'use strict';`) at the top to make your file run in strict mode. This basically throws more errors, prohibits things like `with (obj) {  }`, and changes the behaviour of things like `eval()`. It can be a lifesaver when it comes to finding things like mistyped variables.
- IIFEs. If you're running JavaScript in a browser, it's a good idea to wrap it in an Immediately-Invoked Function Expression like this, preventing variables from being created as properties of `window`:

  ```
  ;(function () {
    // All your code
  })()
  ```
- Rename your variables from things like `comp_choice` to `compChoice` (or `computerChoice`). JavaScript uses CamelCase instead of snake_case.
- Rename your `player` and `pokemon` functions to `Player` and `Pokemon`. There's a convention that constructors (things you call with `new`) begin with a capital letter. Likewise, `Charizard`, `Blastoise`, and `Venasaur` should be renamed to `charizard`, `blastoise`, and `venasaur` as they're not constructors.
- Avoid `new Array('foo', 'bar', 'baz')`. Use `['foo', 'bar', 'baz']` instead. `new Array()` is confusing, as if you try to call it with a number like `new Array(3)`, it'll do `[undefined, undefined, undefined]` instead of `[3]`. It's a good idea to get into the practice of using `[]` instead; it's shorter anyway.
- Don't do `for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {  }`. This creates a global variable called `i`, which can cause bugs if there are other variables called that. Do `var i; for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {  }`, as this makes it a local variable.
- Inside your `user_attack` and `comp_attack` functions, change the variables from `uhigh`, `ulow`, `chigh`, and `clow` to just `high`, `low`, `high`, and `low`. Scoping means that the names don't collide.
- Semicolons. Use them. Or don't. If you want to use them, everything except things like (for instance) `if (foo) {  }`, `while (foo) {  }`, `for (...) {  }`, and `function foo () {  }` should end with `;`. If you don't want to use them, make sure you understand [the rules](http://blog.izs.me/post/2353458699/an-open-letter-to-javascript-leaders-regarding).
- While functions can technically have up to 255 parameters, having too many can make them difficult to use. For example:

  ```
  function lotsOfParametersHere (a, b, c, d, e, f, g) {
    // Do something
  }
  lotsOfParametersHere(4, 7, 97, 123, 76, 23, 42)

  // Can be replaced with:

  function easierToUnderstand (options) {
    var a = options.a
    var b = options.b
    var c = options.c
    var d = options.d
    var e = options.e
    var f = options.f
    var g = options.g

    // Do something
  }
  easierToUnderstand({ a: 4, b: 7, c: 97, d: 123, e: 76, f: 23, g: 42 })

  // Or (ES6):

  function thisUsesES6Destructuring ({ a, b, c, d, e, f, g }) {
    // Do something
  }
  ```